# Is it possible to use flex-wrap without flex grow/shrink to each item but compress the container after wrapping the items

Tags: css, flexbox

### What I want to achieve

I want the items to wrap altogether (not one by one) if it exceeds the container, but I want them also to fit its content after wrapping.

I have other solutions, mainly in JavaScript. However, I prefer to address this issue using CSS only, if possible. Do you have any tricks for this?

Note:
I've tried using flex-grow, shrink, and basis; it compresses, but the items are not wrapping altogether (Every item is not wrapping at the same time).

I want this.
[image]

To wrap like this.
[image]

But I am getting this with flex-wrap. (Line has a space before the wrapped item)
[image]

Here is a sample code.
https://codepen.io/paolojulian/pen/qBgorrb

```html
<body>
  <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: lightcoral;
      column-gap: 3rem;
    }
    .item {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      column-gap: 0.5rem;
    }
    .item--title, .item--value {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item--title">Type</div>
      <div class="item--value">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item--title">Type</div>
      <div class="item--value">Custom test</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ... assume there are many more items here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried   `max-width: fit-content;`    or     `display : inline-flex` ?

Comment: @AliviaPramanik Tried it now but it still stretches.

Comment: you cannot do this

Answer (score -1):

Setting the `width` to `min-content` for `.item` gives the desired result.

```css
.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
    width: min-content; /* this change */
}
```

Result
[image: result image]

Comment: I think not, because setting it to `min-content` will always wrap the item.
I think flex cannot handle this kind of scenario tho.

Comment: Yes, but as per the second screenshot in the question, it seems the text needs to be wrapped always. Setting `min-content` achieves the same. I am guessing I may have misunderstood the question?

Comment: Yeah, My first guess is that this is unachievable without javascript interferance.

But what I want to achieve is that it will just apply sort of `min-content` if the items are `flex wrapped`, but if can fit the container, it should be inline (no wrapping)